# Creating multiple spans in the same javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var text = reader.result;
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    
    const lines = text.split('\n');
    lines.forEach((line) => {
      const div = output.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      const textSplitAroundAt = line.split('Microsoft');
      textSplitAroundAt.forEach((text, i) => {
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
        if (i === textSplitAroundAt.length - 1) return;
        const span = div.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
        span.textContent = 'Microsoft';
        span.className = 'colorMicrosoft';
      });

    });
    document.getElementById('populateAt').textContent = text.split('@').length - 1;
    document.getElementById('populateMicrosoft').textContent = text.split('Microsoft').length - 1;
    document.getElementById('populateGoogle').textContent = text.split('Google').length - 1;
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

```css
.colorMicrosoft
{
 color: blue;
 background-color: red;
}

.colorGoogle
{
 color: red;
 background-color: blue;
}

.colorAt
{
 color: blue;
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>.TXT Log Parser</h1>
</center>

<center>
  <div>I would like the number of times '@' symbol appears here: <span id="populateAt"> ... </span></div>
  <div>I would like the number of times 'Microsoft' symbol appears here: <span id="populateMicrosoft"> ... </span></div>
  <div>I would like the number of times 'Google' symbol appears here: <span id="populateGoogle"> ... </span></div>   
</center> 

<center>
  <h2><input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'></h2>
</center>
<br/>
<div id='output'>...</div>
```

*As long can see if the below code snippet, I am loading a text file into a div. 
    Currently I can tally the number of times a specific strings show up.
    Additionally, I can change the color of each 'Microsoft' string via span.
    However, I cannot seem to add multiple spans for 'Google' and '@'
    Should I use an array, and if so, how?*

Answer (score 0):

You can check line for occurrence of each of three words, without using array

```js
var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var text = reader.result;
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    
    const lines = text.split('\n');
    lines.forEach((line) => {
      const div = output.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      var textSplit = line.split('Microsoft');
      line = textSplit.join('<span class="colorMicrosoft">Microsoft</span>');
      textSplit = line.split('Google');
      line = textSplit.join('<span class="colorGoogle">Google</span>');
      textSplit = line.split('@');
      line = textSplit.join('<span class="colorAt">@</span>');
      div.innerHTML += line;
    });
    document.getElementById('populateAt').textContent = text.split('@').length - 1;
    document.getElementById('populateMicrosoft').textContent = text.split('Microsoft').length - 1;
    document.getElementById('populateGoogle').textContent = text.split('Google').length - 1;
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

```css
.colorMicrosoft
{
 color: blue;
 background-color: red;
}

.colorGoogle
{
 color: red;
 background-color: blue;
}

.colorAt
{
 color: blue;
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>.TXT Log Parser</h1>
</center>

<center>
  <div>I would like the number of times '@' symbol appears here: <span id="populateAt"> ... </span></div>
  <div>I would like the number of times 'Microsoft' symbol appears here: <span id="populateMicrosoft"> ... </span></div>
  <div>I would like the number of times 'Google' symbol appears here: <span id="populateGoogle"> ... </span></div>   
</center> 

<center>
  <h2><input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'></h2>
</center>
<br/>
<div id='output'>...</div>
```

Comment: I think `const div = output.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));` could be wisely to put out (before) `foreach` loop. though you may have a special reason to put it inside.